# Pygame Collision with Changing sprites

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, sprite, collision, game-physics

Alright,

I've looked everywhere and still can't figure out PyGame collisions. I have two sprites: A lander and a moon surface. The moon is an uneven surface with a transparent background, while the lander is a sprite that changes through images with L,D,UP keypresses.

I'm doing *something* wrong when it comes to collision detection. Otherwise, everything in my program is going swimmingly

This is my lander class:

```
class ShipClass(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, image_file, position):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.imageMaster = pygame.image.load(image_file)
    self.image = self.imageMaster
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.imageMaster)
    self.rect.topleft = position

    ## This doesn't work
# def checkCollision(self, Mask):
#   if Mask.overlap_area

def update(self):
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

And this is my lunar surface class:

```
class MoonSurface(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, position):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.imageMaster = pygame.image.load(image_file).convert_alpha()
        self.image = self.imageMaster
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = position
```

What do I need to add to this so that while in my game if the lander hits the moon it sets variable stop to 1 and crash to 1? I plan on also adding landing pads with the MoonSurface class and when it hits them only sets stop to 1.

My sprite is moved as follows:

```
speed = [0,0]
position = [width-524,height-718]
gravity = 0.05
StartingFuel = 100

done = False
while not done:
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit(0)
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit(0)             
    else:
        lander = ShipClass('lander.png', position)

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        lander = ShipClass('landerLeft.png', position)
        # lander.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        speed[0] += 0.3
        fuel -= 1
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        lander = ShipClass('landerRight.png', position)
        # lander.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        speed[0] -= 0.3
        fuel -= 1
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        lander = ShipClass('landerUp.png', position)
        # lander.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        speed[1] -= 0.4
        fuel -= 1

    speed[1] += gravity
    position[0] += speed[0]
        position[1] += speed[1]
        if position[0] < 0:
            position[0] = width
        elif position[0] > width:
            position[0] = 0
    screen.blit(lander.image, position)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to check if the two objects overlap. Luckily Pygame has a built- in function colliderect which checks if two rectangles are overlapping. I've put it into a class method here, as I saw your objects had Pygame rectangle variables named rect:

```
def overlaps (self, other_rect):
   return self.rect.colliderect(other_rect)
```

Here's the documentation: [pygame.Rect](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelist)